# build gradle error reason of proxy and vpn

Tags: android

I cloned this project but when gradle build the project showing this error [ Error:Connection timed out: connect. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle. ] and I tested the vpn and psiphone setting and set host and port of psiphone but this is not work corectly.this is url address of project [$ git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git] and

Comment: and? Can you please complete your question?